# implement memory pools in c

Tags: c, memory, pool

I am confused about the memory pools implementation. I created an memory pool:

```
typedef struct POOL
{
  struct POOL *p_next;
  unsigned short size;
  unsigned short used;
}pool;

pool *p;
p=malloc(pool_size+sizeof(pool));
p->size= pool_size;
p->used= 0;
```

and now I want to divide this memory pool into blocks with block_size, so

```
typedef struct BLOCK
{
 unsigned short size;
 struct BLOCK *b_next;
}block;

block *b=NULL;
b=(block *)&p[block_size+sizeof(block)];
b->size=block_size;
memset(b,0,size+sizeof(block));
p->used+=(size+sizeof(block));
```

and now I want to use the memory of block b, so I just use it as

```
strcpy(b, "hello, world!");
```

am I doing it correctly? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What is `pool`? Is that a `struct`?

Comment: yes, it is a struct contain some information about the pool size, pool id, and a pointer to the next pool.and the block is also a struct.

Comment: You need to describe your structs more & I hope you know this - `p` here is a pointer, `sizeof(pool)` is the size of a pointer not the size of block `pool` points to, the same thing with `sizeof(block)`.

Comment: what kind of memory pool you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

In the following

```
b=(block *)&p[block_size+sizeof(block)];
```

`p` is a pointer to a `pool`, so when you use array indexing on it, the offset will be multiplied by the size of a `pool` struct. This is probably not what you intended.  You probably want to jump over the pool struct, which would be just

```
p+1
```

I don't know what policy you intend to use to carve up the memory after the pool header or how you intend to deal with alignment requirements, so I can't say what additional offset you need beyond that.

Next, you fill in the block size in the block struct, and then proceed to wipe the whole thing out with the `memset`.

So, without knowing what kind of pool allocator you are trying to implement, the best I can do is answer your actual question, and the answer is no, you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do: if I have *p=malloc(1000),I want to divide the memory p into blocks of 200 and 300, and get the address of the blocks and use it. I am confused of how to implement it.

Comment: Try casting your pointers to `uint8_t*` or `uintptr_t` so that you can perform arithmetic in byte units, and then cast them back to the type you actually want. Keep in mind the pool and block headers when you calculate free addresses. You don't want to allocate a block on top of your control structures!